# Import module doesn't work after zipping python dependencies for spark-submit

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I'm new to Spark world and I'm trying to launch some tests on Amazon EMR clusters using Spark 2.1.0 and Python 3.5.

In order to do this I created a virtual environment with conda and zipped the site-packages with all the dependencies I need to launch my script but I can't get spark to work on the cluster in Yarn mode.

I try to launch spark-submit with this command:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 spark-submit \ 
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--py--files filters.py,dependencies.zip \
sparker.py
```

But I get this import error

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 9)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1493796156883_0020/container_1493796156883_0020_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main process()
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1493796156883_0020/container_1493796156883_0020_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1493796156883_0020/container_1493796156883_0020_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 138, in dump_stream for obj in iterator:
File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1493796156883_0020/container_1493796156883_0020_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1541, in func
File "sparker.py", line 52, in applier
File "./dependencies.zip/cv2/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
   from . import cv2
ImportError: cannot import name 'cv2'
```

I see that spark is looking in the right directory but I don't understand why he can't manage to resolve the dependency.

Any help is more than welcome ! And any easier alternative to launch python script (with dependencies) in spark is more than welcome too !

Thank you !

Comment: can you try import cv2

Comment: I tried to import cv2 in pyspark console and it works. It also work in python

Comment: may be you need to try import dependencies.cv2

Comment: I managed to find a workaround solution by installing all dependencies on each cluster and import the needed module inside functions. Thanks fo the help @RakeshKumar

Comment: Great Man, Nice to hear this